# Why does my hasResults getter not work?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

After following along with [Build Bear-Tracking app](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/lwc-build-flexible-apps/record-list?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components) from Trailhead I am trying to use similar features in my own lwc app.

Using a @wire adaptor I load results from an Apex controller, the method that retrieves the data and sets it to `items` works fine. I'm able to iterate through the list of `items` on my .html file.

But when I add a `hasResults` method to my lwc app, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      <template for:each={items.data} for:item="article">
        <!-- code here goes for iterating over individual items -->
      </template>
      <template if:false={hasResults}>
          <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-vertical_small">
              No articles found for this user.
          </div>
      </template>

    </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import loadArticles from '@salesforce/apex/ArticlesController.getUserArticles';

export default class List extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    items;

    @wire(loadArticles, {userId: '$recordId'})
    loadItems(result) {
        this.items = result;
    }

    get hasResults() {
        return (this.items.data.length > 0);
    }

}
```

While I dont have it in the code here, the iteration loop works and is able to output the article lines, when there is no data my `hasResults` failsafe doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because items and the data are null and you are trying to access a property 'length' of a null value . You can put a check like

```
if(this.items && this.items.data) {
   return (this.items.data.length > 0)
}
  return false;
```

If you set `items='';` - It means item is null and `console.log(typeof items);` will return an object. Null is an object.
However, if you just declare `let items;` and `console.log(typeof items);` will return undefined

So if you set `items='';` , your original code should work.

Comment: +1 or just `return this.items && this.items.data && !!this.items.data.length;`

Comment: So why does it work without this on the trailhead but not in my code?

Comment: If you paste the trailhead code, we can look into it. Updated my answer as well